# Yii2: how to pass data column in actionColumn?

Tags: html, gridview, model, yii2

I have a GridView with two columns: **country_name** and an `actionColumn` with a button called **Save**.

The **Save** button is a hiperlink to, for example:

```
http://localhost/countries/view?country_name=Argentina
```

I don't know how to set Argentina to country_name because my view doesn't have a model. I only have data from the column country_name.

```
GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
    'country_name',
    [
      'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
      'template' => '{save}',
      'buttons' => [
        'save' => function($model) {
          return Html::a('Save', ['/countries/view', 'country_name' => $model['country_name']]); // Error: Illegal string offset 'country_name'
        }
      ]
    ],
  ],
])
```

I am using this [Yii2 help](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#hyperlinks).

Comment: Try `$model->country_name`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco. Error: "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: Show your dataprovider,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`ActionColumn:$buttons`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn#$buttons-detail) documentation - model is passed as second argument to button callback:

```
'buttons' => [
    'save' => function($url, $model) {
        return Html::a('Save', ['/countries/view', 'country_name' => $model['country_name']]);
    }
]
```